# How to present a UIScrollView Modaly

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, modal-view

I want to present a modal view with a `UIscrollView` as the content of the view. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, do a viewController and set it's view as the scroll view (in load view)

```
self.view = aScrollView;
```

and present it modally : (in your first viewController)

```
[self presentModalViewController:theViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: I want to know what you meant by aScrollView

Comment: He means a scroll view. Code to create one: [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, w, h)];

Answer (score 1):

Create a standard UIViewController, and give it a UIScrollView as its view member. Then use -[UIViewController presentModalViewController:animated:] on your current (visible) view controller. This will (by default) slide the new one in from the bottom.